# a series of probability questions

Tags: probability

Assume $A$ and $B$ are independent throughout the series of problems.
If $P(A\mid B) = P(B\mid A) = 1/3$, find $P(A \cup B)$.
(I got $5/9$ for this.)

Let $k$ be the fraction you got from the previous problem. $P(A \cup B) = k$, and $P(A\mid B) = 1/3$. Find $P(B \cap A)$. 
(I got $1/3$ for this.)

And the question I'm struggling with is this —
Let $h$ be the fraction you receive. $P(B \cap A) = 1/3$, $P(A\mid B') = 1/3$, find $P(B\mid A)$.

Using the equation $$P(A\mid B')=\frac{P(A\cap B')}{P(B')}=\frac{P(A)-P(A\cap B)}{1-P(B)},$$ I got that $P(B\mid A) = P(B) = 1$, which must be wrong... However, I have double checked all my work so far and don't seem to find any errors yet from the first two questions. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: HINT: Independence means what?

Comment: $P(B\cap A)=P(B)P(A)=P(B\mid A)P(A\mid B)$ follows directly from independence for $A,B$.

Comment: I am not finding any error with your work. If $A,B$ are independent and $P(B\cap A)=P(A\mid B')$ then certainly $P(B\mid A)=1$.

Comment: @drhab — sorry, but I'm still not quite sure how I can apply that knowledge...